Async upload of file using pure JS/AJAX and PHP
UPDATE (16:35 MST TUE 29 OCT 2024)
=====
I have modified the the one-file code to:
<?php

error_reporting (E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', 'on');

$filename = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$location = "../uploads/".$filename;

$str_export = var_export($_FILES, true);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $location)) { echo "<br />\n<br />\n".'Success'."<br />\n<br />\n"; }
else { echo "<br />\n<br />\n".'Failure'."<br />\n<br />\n"; }

echo '$str_export = '.$str_export."<br />\n<br />\n";

file_put_contents('../uploads/'.$filename.'-working.txt', $str_export);

?>
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" >

    bool_asnyc = 1;

</script>

<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
<script type="text/javascript" >
    if (bool_asnyc) document.write("<button type='button' onClick='uploadFile();'>Upload File (async)</button>");
    else document.write("<button onClick='uploadFile();'>Upload File (sync)</button>");
</script>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    async function uploadFile(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();

        const files = document.querySelector('input[name="fileToUpload"]').files;
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", files[0]);
        await fetch(
            'upload.php', 
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData
            }
        ); // await fetch(
        alert("some useless message");
        
    } // async function uploadFile()

    document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', uploadFile);
    
</script>
</body>

</html>

When bool_asnyc = 1; as above, the code should upload the file asynchronously and write a file that contains the var_export of $_FILES, but does neither.
When the page loads, it throws a bunch of errors:
Warning: Undefined array key "fileToUpload" in /opt/homebrew/var/www/pjamesnorris/php/upload-working.php on line 6

Warning: Trying to access array offset on null in /opt/homebrew/var/www/pjamesnorris/php/upload-working.php on line 6

Warning: Undefined array key "fileToUpload" in /opt/homebrew/var/www/pjamesnorris/php/upload-working.php on line 11

Warning: Trying to access array offset on null in /opt/homebrew/var/www/pjamesnorris/php/upload-working.php on line 11

Deprecated: move_uploaded_file(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($from) of type string is deprecated in /opt/homebrew/var/www/pjamesnorris/php/upload-working.php on line 11


Failure

$str_export = array ( )

and does write a 9 bytes plain-text file, -working.txt:
array (
)

which is all to be expected as there is no file that I have selected to upload upon page load.
So, I know just from this the JS and PHP are working, to some extent, the way they should.
But when I click on Upload File (async), the selected file is not uploaded and the var_export file [selected_file_name]-working.txt is not written.
And when bool_asnyc = 0;, everything works as it should. That is, when the page loads I get the same error messages and var_export file -working.txt.
But when I select a file and click on Upload File (sync), the selected file is uploaded and the var_export file [selected_file_name]-working.txt is written, for example, when selecting the file Basic Deduction Rules.png, Basic+Deduction+Rules.png-working.txt contains:
array (
  'fileToUpload' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Basic+Deduction+Rules.png',
    'full_path' => 'Basic+Deduction+Rules.png',
    'type' => 'image/png',
    'tmp_name' => '/private/var/folders/y4/h4q5l_w10175pdvjdlswx7vr0000gn/T/php39Gci5',
    'error' => 0,
    'size' => 88304,
  ),
)

The only thing that leaps out at me is that when uploading a file synchronously, the JS does not display the alert some useless message where as when I try to upload a file asynchronously, the JS does display the some useless message alert.
I'm not sure what to make of all of this and would appreciate any insights anyone can offer.
=====
UPDATE (19:36 MST Tue 15 Oct 2024):
=====
Since a lot of people seem to not be understanding my question, I'll write it again: I want to upload the a file without having to reload the page (which I think is possible but may not be).
As I wrote in my initial posting:
If I click on the "Upload File (async)" button, the form submits and the file is uploaded.
However, if I add type="button" to the <button> tag, the form doesn't submit (as expected), but the file is not uploaded.
I'm not sure how I've failed to communicate that the file uploads successfully if the page reloads because the form has been submitted, but somehow I have.
But to satisfy the person who has posted the comments below, here is a var_dump of $_FILES when the page *reloads due to form submission:
array(1) { ["fileToUpload"]=> array(6) { ["name"]=> string(13) "IMG_1818.webp" ["full_path"]=> string(13) "IMG_1818.webp" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/webp" ["tmp_name"]=> string(26) "/private/var/tmp/phpB7PHbx" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(354262) } }

Maybe I'm using the wrong language in writing "I want to asynchronously upload a file..."--maybe I should write, "I want to upload a file in the background..."?
In any case, I don't want the page to reload when the "Upload File (async)" button is clicked--I want to be able to click the button without the page reloading.
=====
end UPDATE (19:36 MST Tue 15 Oct 2024)
I want to asynchronously upload a file using our JavaScript/AJAX--no jQuery--and PHP without having to submit a form, which I thought was possible with JS/AJAX.
My code is:
<?php

$filename = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$location = "../uploads/".$filename;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $location)) { echo 'Success'; }
else { echo 'Failure'; }

?>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

        async function uploadFile() 
        {
            let formData = new FormData(); 
            formData.append("file", fileToUpload.files[0]);
            await fetch('../php/upload.php', 
            {
                method: "POST", 
                body: formData
            }); // await fetch(
            alert('The file has been uploaded successfully.');
        }; // async function uploadFile()

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
    <button onclick="uploadFile();">Upload File (async)</button>
</form>

</body>

</html>

If I click on the "Upload File (async)" button, the form submits and the file is uploaded.
However, if I add type="button" to the <button> tag, the form doesn't submit (as expected), but the file is not uploaded.
I thought that the problem might be that the php and html were in the same file, so I separated the two to no effect--the upload works without the type="button" but doesn't with it.
I've seen postings about using hidden <iframe>s, but haven't tried implementing one as I don't think this should be necessary.
Do I misunderstand what JS/AJAX and PHP can do, or is there a problem with my code?
Many thanks!

er...have you checked your browser's Console for JS errors? "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: fileToUpload is not defined
at uploadFile;
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick;"  (as visible at https://jsfiddle.net/6dbqkhn5/ - implemented using your HTML/JS, but with type="button" added, as you describe). If you have a problem with some JS code, the first thing to do is debug it and check for errors! That would have been a lot quicker than posting a question here.

By default, buttons have type="submit"; your function doesn't prevent the form from performing its standard submit. Are there any errors in your console?

You need let fileToUpload = document.querySelector("[name='fileToUpload']");

@ADyson I see no JS errors when I run my code.

@P.JamesNorris well then the code you're running can't be the same as what you posted here - my demo proves it throws that error when you click the button

@mykaf I should have written that I know the PHP was going to run every time the page loads. No, there are no console errors. As I said the file uploads when the "Upload File (async)" button is clicked without the 'type="button"' modifier, but the page reloads because the form is submitted.

@Barmar This is what Mohammad si abbou suggests below, but doesn't seem to make a difference--the file is uploaded without the 'type="button"' modifier but but not with it.

They explained that in the answer: when it doesn't have type="button" it defaults to type="submit", so you get normal form submission.

@ADyson I don't see an console error in your jsfiddle [link] https://www.ocetacea.net/pjamesnorris/OneOffs/img/ADyson-jsfiddle.png

"I see no JS errors when I run my code" - do you have the option to keep console content across different requests activated in your browser? If not, the "native" form submission that happens due to the error in your JavaScript, will load a new page, and therefor all existing messages up to that point would get cleared ...

@P.JamesNorris don't use the pretend console in the fiddle screen, use the real one (after you've pressed the "Upload file" button, obviously): https://imgur.com/a/zVKyymm

@C3roe here we're talking about the scenario where form submission has been removed due to adding type="button" to the button - as per the demo I made. OP just didn't use the real dev tools to look for the error message.

here is a var_dump of $_FILES when the page *reloads due to form submission...no, that's not what we asked you for. Why would we want that? We already know that works, and your question isn't about that. We want to see the var_dump from when you upload the file asynchronously using JavaScript. Now that the answer below has fixed your JavaScript error and given you code which successfully sends data to the server, it should be no problem for you to test that (since you said that you think this data never arrives, we need to see some proof).

I'm not sure how I've failed to communicate...you haven't. You explained it very clearly. And we fixed the javascript error which was preventing the asynchronous upload and gave you working code which successfully sends the selected file to the server without reloading the page. Reminder, it's demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/azey78kc/

Thanks for the update. Your code fails because of a simple typo. $_FILES['fileToUpload'] doesn't match formData.append("file". Your PHP returns <br /> <b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "fileToUpload" in <b>D:\Dropbox\code\public_html\test\upload.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br /> (among other related warnings) when you try to do the async upload. Did you not use your browser's Network tool to check the output PHP gives to the async request?? We've talked in earlier comments about how to debug this stuff properly using these tools.

If you notice, the fully-working answer from mohammad si abbou below already corrected this mistake for you in the PHP, using $_FILES['file'] so that it matches what your JS is sending. But you didn't note that or copy it, and you didn't check for errors properly using the browser tools available. Hours of time wasted over a silly typo which had already been fixed for you 2 weeks ago, all because you didn't use the Network tool to debug properly, as we also told you to do, 2 weeks ago. If you don't do basic debugging, or double-check your work carefully, you'll continually have silly issues.

@ADyson I think I'm getting on your nerves and I apologize. But if you look at my 16:35 MST TUE 29 OCT 2024 update, I think you'll see that I've implemented Mohammad si Abbou's correction.

Er, no you haven't. Look at your code again. You've written $filename = $_FILES['fileToUpload'], as I already pointed out. fileToUpload doesn't match file. Muhammed wrote $filename = $_FILES['file']; so that the array key name matches the key JS is sending in the formData object (in formData.append("file"... ). It's not rocket science...php won't find the file if you tell it to look in the wrong place

You have multiple issues here :
First the fileToUpload.files[0] returns an error since fileToUpload is not defined.
Second the event is linked to the button, that's why when you change it to type submit the page refreshes, it should be linked to the form and adding e.preventDefault(); to prevent refresh.
also, the upload code always runs you need to change it to only run on post-requests.
here is a code that fixes the frontend issues :
<?php

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$location = "../uploads/".$filename;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location)) { echo 'Success'; }
else { echo 'Failure'; }

?>
<html>

<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
    <button type="submit">Upload File (async)</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    async function uploadFile(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const files = document.querySelector('input[name="fileToUpload"]').files;
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", files[0]);
        await fetch('../php/upload.php', {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        }); // await fetch(
        alert('The file has been uploaded successfully.');
    } // async function uploadFile()

    document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', uploadFile);
</script>
</body>


</html>


I've copied and pasted your code and it doesn't seem to work.
But adding the 'type="button"' modifier to the  tag, shouldn't that have the same effect as your e.preventDefault();.
And doesn't your document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', uploadFile);
have the effect of passing uploadFile only if the form is submitted which will reload the page which is what I'm trying to avoid?

@P.JamesNorris the code in this answer works perfectly well - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/azey78kc/ . P.S. But adding the 'type="button"' modifier to the <button> tag, shouldn't that have the same effect as your e.preventDefault();...yes it would, this is just an alternative approach. doesn't your document.querySelector("form").addEventListener('submit', uploadFile); have the effect of passing uploadFile only if the form is submitted which will reload the page which is what I'm trying to avoid...no because e.preventDefault(); cancels the submit event. Your two comments are contradictory

@ADyson I'm not sure how my two statements are contradictory and I'm not sure how jsfiddle can show anything more than there are no JS errors--it can not show that the file actually uploads, can it?
What I want is to click on the button and have the file uploaded without the page reloading. Whether this is done via e.preventDefault(); or using 'type="button"' is of no importance to me.
In any case, neither method works, the file does not upload.
It only uploads if I leave either out and when I do that, the page reloads.

@P.JamesNorris contradictory because you acknowledge in the first one that preventDefault() has the same effect as type="button" (i.e. cancelling the form submit), but then in the second one worrying that using the "submit" event would submit the form, even though the callback attached to it involves the aforementioned "preventDefault", which you realised cancels the standard submission.

@P.JamesNorris it can not show that the file actually uploads, can it...well it will show what's sent to the server - you can see in the Network tool what the payload of the request is. Obviously it doesn't demonstrate what PHP would do with it, but aside from some unforseen other error in the PHP code, there's no particular reason why PHP wouldn't then be able to read the uploaded file data into the $_FILES array and then process it. But your question was about why the form didn't send via AJAX, which we've resolved by removing the error about the missing filesToUpload variable.

@P.JamesNorris What I want is to click on the button and have the file uploaded without the page reloading...which is exactly what this code, including the JSFiddle demo I made using it, both demonstrate happening - look at https://imgur.com/a/C7k9wy2 . In any case, neither method works... either a) you've done something differently, or b) there's actually an error on your PHP side which is causing the file not to be saved (note that this is not the same as the file not being uploaded... if it reached the server then it was uploaded.

@P.JamesNorris If a problem occurs during PHP meaning it's not saved to the disk, that's a different issue. Have you attempted to debug your code to differentiate between those two things? You can inspect the network tool to see what's sent, you can var_dump($_FILES) to see what PHP thinks it's received and whether it shows any of the file upload error codes in there, you can ensure you check for PHP warnings in case move_uploaded_file failed, and so on. Have you made any attempt to do that kind of basic testing, to narrow down what the current problem is?

@P.JamesNorris note that if PHP doesn't log any errors to a file, you can again use the Response tab of the Network tool, inside the request to upload.php, to see what PHP outputs into its standard output in response to that (Your fetch code doesn't make any attempt to read back the response that PHP outputs, so until/unless you add such code you won't see any response in the code - you've got the alert('The file has been uploaded successfully.'); but that will just happen automatically and completely ignores what PHP actually returned).

@ADyson Have you seen my latest update?
What and how would you suggest I "attempt to read back the response that PHP outputs"?
